# Convert my list output to a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

How do i convert my list output to a data frame? below is a sample of the code and data

```
  import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import datetime
    dat=pd.read_csv()
    dat.Date = dat.Date.apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, "%d-%m-%Y"))
    dat.index = dat.Date
    dat = dat.drop(['Date'], axis=1)
################################################################
   #Provide Input parameters

    Decay=0.4 
    Decay_Dur=15 #(in days)
    Return_Avg_Dur=15 #(in days)

################################################################
    Weights=[]
    Weights=[pow(i,((2*Decay)-1)) for i in range(1,Decay_Dur+1)] # Calculate Weights
    Weights=Weights[::-1] #Reverse the order
    fin_dat=[0]


    for j in range(1,(dat.shape[0]-Decay_Dur)):
       Sum_Weighted_Index=0
       for i in range(j,Decay_Dur+j):
            temp=Weights[i-j]*dat.iat[i-1,2] #
            Sum_Weighted_Index+=temp
       fin_dat.append(Sum_Weighted_Index)

Date    SPX Index   Surprise Index  S&P 500 Daily Return
19-07-2007  1553.08 -0.0563 0.0045
20-07-2007  1534.1  0   -0.0122
23-07-2007  1541.57 0   0.0049
24-07-2007  1511.04 0   -0.0198
25-07-2007  1518.09 0   0.0047
26-07-2007  1482.66 0   -0.0233
27-07-2007  1458.95 0   -0.016
30-07-2007  1473.91 0   0.0103
31-07-2007  1455.27 -0.0867 -0.0126
01-08-2007  1465.81 -0.1529 0.0072
02-08-2007  1472.2  0   0.0044
03-08-2007  1433.06 -0.0848 -0.0266
06-08-2007  1467.67 0   0.0242
07-08-2007  1476.71 0   0.0062
08-08-2007  1497.49 0   0.0141
09-08-2007  1453.09 0   -0.0296
10-08-2007  1453.64 0   0.0004
13-08-2007  1452.92 0.0138  -0.0005
14-08-2007  1426.54 0   -0.0182
15-08-2007  1406.7  0   -0.0139
16-08-2007  1411.27 -0.1289 0.0032
17-08-2007  1445.94 0   0.0246
20-08-2007  1445.55 0   -0.0003
21-08-2007  1447.12 0   0.0011
22-08-2007  1464.07 0   0.0117
23-08-2007  1462.5  0   -0.0011
24-08-2007  1479.37 0   0.0115
27-08-2007  1466.79 0   -0.0085
```

Comment: What is a `list output` and what is a `expected result` ?

Comment: As I know, normal list can be change using `pd.DataFrame( normal_list )`

Comment: fin_dat is the list out put. :) that works.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you also please help me on how to assign the index of dat to pd.DataFrame(fin_dat) inside the loop so that i know the exact dates of my Sum_Weighted_Index. for example if the ith loop is from 1 to 20 then the dat.index[20] should be the index for the first index value for fin_dat

Comment: Create dictionary in place of list and use  `pd.DataFrame( normal_dictionary )`. You can also do `pd.DataFrame( [ list_1, list_2 , ...] )`

Comment: BTW: `read_csv( ..., parse_dates=['Date'])` can convert column `Date` from text into `datetime`. Or you can use `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%d-%m-%Y")`

Comment: pd.DataFrame(dat.Date[i],fin_dat) gives me an error pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: What do you try to do ? Do you want to use two lists to create table with two columns `pd.DataFrame( [dat.Date,fin_dat] )` or you want to use `dat.Date[i]` as index for row `fin_dat` - `pd.DataFrame( { dat.Date[i]: fin_dat } )`

Comment: I have a dataframe dat and i have a list fin_dat. I need to create a new data frame inside the jth loop with two columns A and B. row 1 of col A would be dat.Date[i] where i is the last value of the ith loop (if i loop is from 1 to 50 then i is 50) and  row 1 of col B is the fin_dat. I tried for j=1 and ran the complete ith loop after that pd.DataFrame( { dat.Date[i]: Sum_Weighted_Index } ) i get an error ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index

Comment: Can you add expected result in question ?

Comment: when i run the above code for just j=1 and >>> fin_dat
[0, -0.26262186081233341]
>>> fin_dat[1]
-0.26262186081233341
>>> dat.Date[i]
Timestamp('2007-08-09 00:00:00')
>>> pd.DataFrame(dat.Date[i],fin_dat[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ravi Shankar\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 277, in __init__
    raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
>>>

Comment: `pd.DataFrame()` expect one argument - it can be ditionary of columns or list of rows - so you forgot `[ ]` in `pd.DataFrame( [dat.Date[i],fin_dat[1] ])` but this way you create a lot of DataFrames

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The above pd.DataFrame( [dat.Date[i],fin_dat[1] ]) gives me 1 column and 2 rows data frame but i want 1 row and 2 columns where column 1 is Date and column 2 is fin_dat. to address your second point about creating too many data frames i did not understand. for each j, i would be appending to the earlier data frame. Thank you once again

Comment: I think you could create new column in `dat` (`dat['new'] = 0`) and add directly to that column - like this: `dat.iat[j,4] = sum_weighted_index` (use correct number in place of `4`)

Comment: You can use dictionary `pd.DataFrame( {'date':dat.Date[i], 'result': fin_dat[1] } )`, or you can transform table using `.T` - `pd.DataFrame( [dat.Date[i],fin_dat[1] ]).T`

Comment: You can use even `dat['new'].iat[j] = sum_weighted_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use your code and then create new version using pandas functions.

It's all my "notes" - and result at the end.

Check whether the results are correct.

```
import pandas as pd

#--- generate some data ---

#dates = pd.date_range( '01-01-2010', periods=30, freq='D' )
#values = range(0,30)

#dat = pd.DataFrame( {'Date':dates, 'val1':values, 'val2':values} )
#dat.index = dat.Date

#print dat

data = '''Date    SPX   Surprise  S&P-500
19-07-2007  1553.08 -0.0563 0.0045
20-07-2007  1534.1  0   -0.0122
23-07-2007  1541.57 0   0.0049
24-07-2007  1511.04 0   -0.0198
25-07-2007  1518.09 0   0.0047
26-07-2007  1482.66 0   -0.0233
27-07-2007  1458.95 0   -0.016
30-07-2007  1473.91 0   0.0103
31-07-2007  1455.27 -0.0867 -0.0126
01-08-2007  1465.81 -0.1529 0.0072
02-08-2007  1472.2  0   0.0044
03-08-2007  1433.06 -0.0848 -0.0266
06-08-2007  1467.67 0   0.0242
07-08-2007  1476.71 0   0.0062
08-08-2007  1497.49 0   0.0141
09-08-2007  1453.09 0   -0.0296
10-08-2007  1453.64 0   0.0004
13-08-2007  1452.92 0.0138  -0.0005
14-08-2007  1426.54 0   -0.0182
15-08-2007  1406.7  0   -0.0139
16-08-2007  1411.27 -0.1289 0.0032
17-08-2007  1445.94 0   0.0246
20-08-2007  1445.55 0   -0.0003
21-08-2007  1447.12 0   0.0011
22-08-2007  1464.07 0   0.0117
23-08-2007  1462.5  0   -0.0011
24-08-2007  1479.37 0   0.0115
27-08-2007  1466.79 0   -0.0085'''

from StringIO import StringIO

dat = pd.DataFrame.from_csv( StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

#------------------------------------------

decay = 0.4 
decay_dur = 15 # (in days)
return_avg_dur = 15 # (in days)

#--- old version ---

weights = [ pow(i,(2*decay)-1) for i in range(1,decay_dur+1) ] # Calculate Weights
weights = weights[::-1] #Reverse the order

#weights = [ pow(i,(2*decay)-1) for i in range(1,decay_dur+1) ][::-1]

#fin_dat=[0]

dat['old'] = 0.0

for j in range(1,(dat.shape[0]-decay_dur)):

    sum_weighted_index = 0

    for i in range(j,decay_dur+j):
        #sum_weighted_index += weights[i-j] * dat.iat[i-1,2] #
        sum_weighted_index += weights[i-j] * dat['S&P-500'].iat[i-1] #

    #fin_dat.append(sum_weighted_index)
    dat['old'].iat[j] = sum_weighted_index

    #print sum_weighted_index

#--- new version ---

#def sum_weighted_index(data):
#    result = 0
#    for w, d in zip(weights, data):
#        result += w * d
#    return result

def sum_weighted_index(data):
    return sum( w * d for w, d in zip(weights, data) )

dat['new'] = pd.rolling_apply(dat['S&P-500'], decay_dur, sum_weighted_index).shift(-decay_dur+2).fillna(0)

print dat
```

result

```
                SPX  Surprise  S&P-500       old       new
Date                                                      
2007-07-19  1553.08   -0.0563   0.0045  0.000000  0.000000
2007-07-20  1534.10    0.0000  -0.0122 -0.010550 -0.010550
2007-07-23  1541.57    0.0000   0.0049 -0.044731 -0.044731
2007-07-24  1511.04    0.0000  -0.0198 -0.034384 -0.034384
2007-07-25  1518.09    0.0000   0.0047 -0.036309 -0.036309
2007-07-26  1482.66    0.0000  -0.0233 -0.042091 -0.042091
2007-07-27  1458.95    0.0000  -0.0160 -0.055676 -0.055676
2007-07-30  1473.91    0.0000   0.0103 -0.035502 -0.035502
2007-07-31  1455.27   -0.0867  -0.0126 -0.000058 -0.000058
2007-01-08  1465.81   -0.1529   0.0072 -0.008301 -0.008301
2007-02-08  1472.20    0.0000   0.0044 -0.000615 -0.000615
2007-03-08  1433.06   -0.0848  -0.0266  0.006442  0.006442
2007-06-08  1467.67    0.0000   0.0242  0.001076  0.001076
2007-07-08  1476.71    0.0000   0.0062  0.000000  0.027115
2007-08-08  1497.49    0.0000   0.0141  0.000000  0.002560
2007-09-08  1453.09    0.0000  -0.0296  0.000000  0.000000
2007-10-08  1453.64    0.0000   0.0004  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-13  1452.92    0.0138  -0.0005  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-14  1426.54    0.0000  -0.0182  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-15  1406.70    0.0000  -0.0139  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-16  1411.27   -0.1289   0.0032  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-17  1445.94    0.0000   0.0246  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-20  1445.55    0.0000  -0.0003  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-21  1447.12    0.0000   0.0011  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-22  1464.07    0.0000   0.0117  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-23  1462.50    0.0000  -0.0011  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-24  1479.37    0.0000   0.0115  0.000000  0.000000
2007-08-27  1466.79    0.0000  -0.0085  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been a brilliant learning exp for me